# Helper function interfacing different libraries on native Java vs Android?

Tags: java, android, gradle

How do I cleanly write a helper function that uses different libraries (with different interfaces) on Java versus Android?  This must have been asked before, but all I've found are a hundred people being told that #ifdef still doesn't exist.

I'm working on an in-house utility library.  Nearly all of the library runs cleanly on Android, but I do some Base64 conversions, which are done differently on the two platforms.

**Java:** `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter`

**Android:** `android.util.Base64`

This would be easy with #ifdef, but I don't want to add a preprocessor for something that ten thousand people must have solved before me.  I suppose I could also try to find a library that runs on both, but it does seem better to use the native Android library on Android if possible.

The only real solution I've come up with is to write a new "helper function library" implemented appropriately for each platform, and link differently based on target -- but that seems like some awfully complicated dependency magic for such a simple problem.

Is there a better way than expanding my nice clean single library into 3-choose-2 plus complicated gradle magic?

Comment: If you want to do this at run-time, then how about using a configuration file?

Comment: Just copy a code from Android converter to your own library. It looks fairly simple and has the same permissive Apache license as the rest of Android frameworks.